# how to add the table row after the given id in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/g2hrm9cb/)

How to add the `<tr>` after the given `<tr>` ID in JQuery

Below is the JQuery code :

```
$('#tableclick').click(function(){
            $('#tr_second').append('<tr><td>test1</td><td>test2</td><td>test3</td></tr>');
});
```

**Expected Output**

```
test1   test2   test3
test1   test2   test3
test1   test2   test3
```

Comment: did you try append tr to table id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `after()` instead of `append()` [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/g2hrm9cb/2/)

```
$('#tableclick').click(function() {
  $('#tr_second').after('<tr><td>test1</td><td>test2</td><td>test3</td></tr>');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there just change the function from ***append*** to ***after***

Jquery Code

```
$('#tableclick').click(function(){
            $('#tr_second').after('<tr><td>test1</td><td>test2</td><td>test3</td></tr>');
});
```

Comment: We don't need duplicate answers (this one was already posted in @Nenad's answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/42087996/4281779)

Answer (score 0):

**[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/g2hrm9cb/3/)**.

If you want to append at the end of the table you should use `#append_tr` instead like :

```
$('#append_tr').append('<tr><td>test1</td><td>test2</td><td>test3</td></tr>');
```

Else to add it after `#tr_second` you should use **[`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/)** instead :

```
var new_tr = '<tr><td>test1</td><td>test2</td><td>test3</td></tr>';
$( new_tr ).insertAfter( "#tr_second" );
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('#tableclick').on('click', function(){
  var new_tr = '<tr><td>test1</td><td>test2</td><td>test3</td></tr>';
  $( new_tr ).insertAfter( "#tr_second" );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id='tableclick'>ADD New Row</button>
<br><br>
<table border='1'>
  <tr id='tr_second'>
    <td>test 1000</td>
    <td>test 2000</td>
    <td>test 3000</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```